# How to order a window to front if you are not in the Application in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, nswindow, makekeyandordertofront

Is there a way to make a "makeKeyAndOrderToFront" without beeing in the Application?

If I am in Safari and in the Menu Bar there is a MenuItem to my App, after I press this, i want to show a window of my App in the Front (makeKeyAndOrderToFront makes this just if you are in the Application).

Which way can I use? And how can I animate this Window (like Tweeties Add new Tweet -> atebits.com).

Thank you!

Comment: More information, please. Describe your menu extra with relationship to your application. Do you have the menu extra and a separate application, or is the menu extra the application (and it has a hidden window)?

Comment: Both Windows are in one XIB - both are using the same Controller

Comment: This is still too vague.

Answer (score 22):

As you've discovered, changing the window order within your application does not have any impact on which application is active. You can bring your application to the foreground by activating it:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

If your application had a dock icon the behavior would be similar to the user clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript would be a trivially easy way to make your app frontmost. It won't be doing any animation, though.

```
tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "My Application" to true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update if anyone needs a solution for Swift vs ObjC:

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the highest voted answer from 13 years ago. The only difference is Swift vs. Objective-C. Your answer has nothing to do with Xcode 14.3 or macOS 13.0.

Comment: OK, edited so it makes clear it's a Swift vs ObjC answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to accomplish what you want, if I understand the question correctly, is to have your application respond to an Apple event which you send to it after your menu item is selected which will bring your application and desired window to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your application has a connection to the window server (which it will if it's using AppKit or Carbon), you can use the Core Services function `SetFrontProcess()` to bring it to the fore. `SetFrontProcessWithOptions()` can be used to bring only the frontmost non-floating window of your app to the fore. These functions appear to be available to 64-bit applications, but if you're targeting 10.6+, you're likely better off using the [`NSRunningApplication` class.](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Something like

```
[[[NSRunningApplication
   runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:ident] lastObject]
 activateWithOptions:0]
```

should do the trick.